# How to modify Xcode project settings from command line? - so it produces a MacAppStore app and a non-MacAppStore app

Tags: xcode, jenkins

I have a Xcode project that outputs a Mac app that is distributed outside the Mac App Store. It works fine. Now, the client wants it in the Mac App Store. To achieve this I've disabled several features of the original app. Now, I'm facing the question: **how to integrate the build process of the Mac App Store app in a painful-less way?** For the Non-Mac App Store app we use Jenkins.

I thought it could be possible to keep the non-Mac App Store project settings and then enable/disable/modify it with command line. Errrrr!. I'm wondering if anyone else have faced the same situation and how did you solve it?. Or maybe I'm opening Pandora's box wit my current approach.

To list the stuff I need to enable/disable:

1. Disable source code. Solution: ifdefs
2. Enable the app-sandbox. Solution: adding 'com.apple.security.app-sandbox' to  entitlements.
3. Delete dependencies in the 'Target dependencies'. Solution: ????.
4. Delete libraries in the "link binary with libraries". Please, note that the libraries are already listed in Xcode project settings, I want to delete them.
5. Change the signing profile. Solution: Add a new scheme with the right values (Mac App Store).

FYI. I'm using Xcode 5.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

To modify Xcode project settings from command line, you could try a python module [pbxproj](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj).

You can `pip install pbxproj` to have it.

And here's an example provided in the official repo:

```
from pbxproj import XcodeProject
# open the project
project = XcodeProject.load('myapp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj')

# add a file to it, force=false to not add it if it's already in the project
project.add_file('MyClass.swift', force=False)

# set a Other Linker Flags
project.add_other_ldflags('-ObjC')

# save the project, otherwise your changes won't be picked up by Xcode
project.save()
```

Comment: Tried this with a Xcode 3.2-compatilbe project and I got the error "AttributeError: 'XcodeProject' object has no attribute 'objects'"

Comment: @mondaugen The pbxproj project says "This module can read, modify, and write a .pbxproj file from an Xcode 4+ projects". So maybe upgrade your project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Xcode 5.1.1. But if you're already using a new scheme to change the signing profile, why can't you use it to delete the dependencies and linked libraries? These can be changed in the *Build Phases* for this specific target. Or you have some more context to explain why you can't do this?